# Android app with only a PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

The app I'm currently developing is in dire need of a user interface. Currently, it is only a togglable service with no user interface. I want to incorporate an app that opens to a PreferenceScreen for it's MainActivity with a few options, and that's it. How would I approach that? (I have very little experience in user interface design for Android devices, [and I've already checked this out.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html))

Answer (score 2):

Check out PreferenceActivity.  Its a preference screen built into Android that can read the settings in from xml and write the settings to a shared preference.